# How to search, replace and highlight all occurrances of a text in tinyMCE?

Tags: asp.net, tinymce

I have integrated tinyMCE in my asp.net web application,
I wonder how to search, replace and highlight all occurrances of a word in tinyMCE editor?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the tinymce searchreplace plugin. This one will lets you search and replace the editor content step by step or replace all occurences. To highlight all occurances you will implmement something of your own. Selecting is not possible here due to the fact that you would need to select differnt parts of the content. The solution to this would be to wrap the occurences into spans each and give them a style.